# Transform Differential Equation to System of Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

So this problem may be really simple and there's one small thing I'm missing, but I'm just stumped.

Find 4 solutions of the ODE
$$y^{(4)} − 4 = 0$$
by transforming the ODE into a system of 4 first order differential equations.

I've had no problem solving similar equations, but the lack of any other $y$ value and just a constant has left me confused.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a typo? It seems silly to have to create a system of 4 odes to solve something like this which you can just integrate. $$y=\frac16 x^4+Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D$$

Comment: @JohnDoe. Very creative nick name, I'm impressed.

Comment: @JohnDoe No typo on my part at least, that's what the question says. I'm guessing the problem itself isn't a typo either because it has a note saying there's obviously an easier way to do it, but we are to turn it into a system of equations.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Let the variables be $y, x = y', w = y'', v = y'''$ and introduce equations like $x=y', w=x'$, etc.

Comment: I tried to initially do it this way and turn it into a matrix to solve using eigenvectors, but you're left with a whole row and a column of 0s so it makes no sense. And I'm unsure of what to do with the constant slapped onto the end as we have never done a problem with a constant.

Comment: @DavisM12 you have 5 equations $x=y', w=x', v=w',u=v'$ and your original one $u=4'$ - this is a $5 \times 5$ matrix with no zero rows or zero columns